# Nginx with TLS 1.3

Tags: nginx, webserver, tls1.3

Trying to use TLS 1.3 certificates in Nginx (1.15.8), I found that the official Nginx was built with openssl 1.1.0, where as for TLS 1.3, openssl 1.1.1 is needed.

To solve this, I built my own openssl 1.1.1 from sources and then nginx from sources (using the openssl I just built). It works perfectly.
BUT - I was unable to find any official Nginx distribution with this support built in. In Debian or any other Linux.

Has anyone ever tried this and found an official, pre-built solution?

EDIT: My Docker based solution in https://github.com/eldada/nginx-tls13-docker.

Comment: same issue on macOS here with Nginx 1.15.12.  Built with OpenSSL 1.0.2r  (26 Feb 2019).  Would you recommend just building locally @Eldad ?

Comment: Are you running Nginx directly on your Mac? Would you be open to running in in Docker. If so, see my solution: https://github.com/eldada/nginx-tls13-docker

Comment: I definitely would have tried your plan!  But I had built it all from source, like you, before I read your answer :o)  I could have saved a lot of time if I had read this first:  https://gist.github.com/beatfactor/a093e872824f770a2a0174345cacf171

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**UPDATE**:  With the release of [Ubuntu 18.04.3](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2019-August/000248.html) which includes OpenSSL 1.1.1, TLS 1.3 is now supported on NGINX 1.14 and later.

As of this writing, there are three distributions that have OpenSSL 1.1.1 and NGINX 1.15:  [Ubuntu 18.10](http://releases.ubuntu.com/18.10/) (which is not an LTS release), [FreeBSD 12.0](https://www.freebsd.org/releases/12.0R/announce.html), and [Alpine 3.9](https://alpinelinux.org/posts/Alpine-3.9.0-released.html).

There are plans to move 18.04 (which is an LTS release) to OpenSSL 1.1.1, but there is currently an open bug tracking its inclusion:  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssl/+bug/1797386  Unfortunately OpenSSL 1.1.1 did not land in Ubuntu 18.04.2 which has been released.

Answer (score 0):

I found that Nginx build and ship their binary with the same openssl as in the target distribution.

> Packages in the nginx repository are compiled with OpenSSL as 
>   shipped by default in the particular OS. As such, nginx on Debian 
>   9 is compiled with OpenSSL 1.1.0f.
>
> OpenSSL 1.1.1 is currently available in Ubuntu 18.10, and 
>   corresponding nginx package as available from nginx.org are built 
>   with OpenSSL 1.1.1.

This is taken from [nginx forum answer](https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,282657,282674#msg-282674).